# Changing the charset to utf8 for all tables and fields in mysql

Tags: mysql

After search, I found (just read, but did not try) that I can use the below command to change the charset for all the fields and tables of a mysql database to utf8:

```
mysql --database=dbname -B -N -e "SHOW TABLES" \
| awk '{print "SET foreign_key_checks = 0; ALTER TABLE", $1, "CONVERT TO CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci; SET foreign_key_checks = 1; "}' \
| mysql --database=dbname &
```

But I have some questions on it:

Where is the username and password to be given to be able to login to mysql database?

Why to use the &?

Should I type it as it is without username and wait? How can I know the situation?

Answer (score 0):

> Where is the username and password to be given to be able to login to
>   mysql database

You might need to provide them in the two commands if you haven't already put them in environment variables.

> Why to use the &?  Should I type it as it is without username and wait? How can I know the situation?

This runs the process in the background.  You should get an error if it fails.  You can run it without the ampersand to know when it's complete.